# RegEx for matching lines starting with [ and ending with ]

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I am trying to find the lines that start with [ and ends with ] in a file. I am using regex, but not able to get the result.

I have tried regex with various options, e.g., \s, \S, \w and \W.

```py
import re
infile=open("C:\\Users\\Downloads\\Files\\processed.csv","r") 
myregex = re.compile(r'(^\[)(\]$)') 
list=[] 
for groups in myregex.findall(infile.read()):
    item=''.join(groups)
    cleanitem=item.replace('\n','')
    list.append(cleanitem)
print (list)
infile.close()
```

It should print all the lines that start with [ and ends with ].

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here, we can find a simple expression with a capturing group, if we like, something similar to:

```
^(\[.+\])$
```

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"^(\[.+\])$"

test_str = ("[ and ends with ]\n"
    " [ and ends with ]")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/1Z02qx/1/)

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified/changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/1Z02qx/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]